# Using .count() Pandas and assigning to y axis returns empty chart in Seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to do a simple `.count()` for the number of times the word "pos" and "neg" appear so that I can apply this to the Y-axis of my barplot on Seaborn.

Here's my code:

```
df['score'] = df['compound'].apply(lambda x: 'pos' if x>= 0 else 'neg')
df['overall'] = df[(df.score == "pos") & (df.score == "neg")].count()

plt.figure(2)
chart_2 = sns.barplot(x='Category', y='overall', data=df)
```

When I run this, plt.figure(2) returns an empty chart. I've tried `.sum()` which doesn't work and also returns an empty chart.

If I execute this, it'll return the overall total without breaking it down per `Category` in the x-ais. For example, all Categories have a total of 58 which is the dataframe total.

```
df['overall'] = df['score'].count()
```

`.value_counts()` also returns an empty chart.

I've run out of ideas on why this might be the case!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(df.score == "pos") & (df.score == "neg")` will give false for all rows. And you will get an empty dataframe ?

Comment: @Psidom oh, I thought it would do the exact opposite and give me a count of both "pos" and "neg" as 2 separate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `(df.score == "pos") & (df.score == "neg")` combines via an `AND` relation and will give `False` in all cases.  Using an `OR` as in `(df.score == "pos") | (df.score == "neg")` will give True in all cases.  But, it won't differentiate between categories, so `df['overall']` also will be 58 everywhere.

The easiest way to create a bar plot of counts is seaborn's `sns.countplot()`. You can set `x='Category'` to count each category. `hue='score'` will split via score.

To directly create a barplot, and do the counting via pandas, you'd need something like `df['overall'] = df['Category'].apply(lambda cat: (df['Category'] == cat).sum())`.  Here, `(df['Category'] == cat)` creates an array of boolean `True` and `False` values. When `sum()` is called onto these, `True` is considered `1` and `False` as `0`, so `sum()` will count the number of `True` values.

Pandas' preferred way to count by category would be via `groupby('Category')` and then take the `size()` of each group.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'compound': [-20, -10, 100, 200, 300, -20, -10, 100, -10, 100, 200, 300],
                   'Category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']})
df['score'] = df['compound'].apply(lambda x: 'pos' if x >= 0 else 'neg')

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(14, 4))

sns.countplot(data=df, x='Category', hue='score', palette='rocket', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Countplot: Score per category')
ax1.locator_params(axis='y', integer=True)

sns.countplot(data=df, x='Category', palette='turbo', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Countplot: Overall sum per category')

df['overall'] = df['Category'].apply(lambda cat: (df['Category'] == cat).sum())
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Category', y='overall', palette='turbo', ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('Barplot: Using the "overall" column')

df_counts = df.groupby('Category', as_index=False).size()
sns.barplot(data=df_counts, x='Category', y='size', palette='turbo', ax=ax4)
ax4.set_title('Barplot: Using groupby')

sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.countplot vs sns.barplot]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to go through each example for me! I really appreciate it and I've gone for the simpler option of using the `countplot` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had marked it as the accepted answer. Thanks again for your help